# Evaluate Ternary Logic

Tags: code-golf, logic-gates, combinatory-logic

## Objective

Given an expression involving ternary values, evaluate it into a ternary value.

## Ternary Values

The three truth values in question are the values of Haskell's `Ordering`, namely `LT`, `EQ`, and `GT`. They stand for "less-than", "equal-to", and "greater-than", respectively. Furthermore, they themselves have an order; `LT` is the least, and `GT` is the greatest.

## Operators

The binary operators for the ternary values are Haskell's `min`, `max`, `compare`, and `(<>)`, all instantiated for `Ordering`. They're defined as:

```
min|LT EQ GT
---|--------
LT |LT LT LT
EQ |LT EQ EQ
GT |LT EQ GT
```

```
max|LT EQ GT
---|--------
LT |LT EQ GT
EQ |EQ EQ GT
GT |GT GT GT
```

```
compare|LT EQ GT
-------|--------
  LT   |EQ LT LT
  EQ   |GT EQ LT
  GT   |GT GT EQ
```

```
(<>)|LT EQ GT
----|--------
 LT |LT LT LT
 EQ |LT EQ GT
 GT |GT GT GT
```

## I/O Format

Flexible. You may represent the values and the operators in an arbitrary way. In particular, the expression may be in [Polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation).

## Examples

Here, the shorthands are `T` for `LT`, `0` for `EQ`, `1` for `GT`, `&` for `min`, `|` for `max`, `c` for `compare`, and `s` for `(<>)`. The expressions are in Polish notation.

```
Expression, Evaluation

c01, T
sT1, T
|0&1T, 0
|&1T0, 0
s0s00, 0
s0s01, 1
sTcTT, T
cs10T, 1
cs01&|01T, 1
```

Comment: Can I take a fully parenthesized infix expression as input, such as `"(0 | (1 & T))"`?

Comment: @Bubbler Yes, of course.

Comment: I think this is similar to Kleene's 3VL system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3), 1 byte

```
Ė
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyIiLCIiLCLEliIsIiIsIjAgMSDiiKggMCAxIEcgMU4gZyAtwrEiLCIzLjQuMiJd)

Accepts input in reverse polish notation with `LT` represented by `1N`, `EQ` represented by `0`, and `GT` represented by `1`. `min` is `g`, `max` is `G`, `compare` is `-±`, and `<>` is `∨`.

These operators are, respectively, `min`, `max`, `difference` into `sign`, and `logical or`, which is all these really are when we represent them like such.

---

As much as this feels like cheating, if I were required to follow the test cases' format I think the easiest method is probably to [convert from prefix to postfix notation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/119754/prefix-notation-to-postfix-notation), map the characters to the above strings, and then evaluate, which is really not any more interesting in my opinion.

That said, here's a method without evaluate, though I honestly find it less clever because it's just trivial implementation. It takes the input like in the test cases but still in reverse polish notation because inverting it is already a different challenge.

#### [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3), 59 bytes

```
Ṛ0Ḣ&Ṛ₳:"01T"$c["01"$Ḟ&|$ṫ$ṫ$^"&|cs"$ḞᵈgᵈGᵉ-±ᵈ∨;JJiĖ&)"01T"i
```

[Try it Online! (link is to literate version)](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#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)

Here's a brief explanation of how this works:

```
Ṛ0Ḣ&Ṛ                  sets up [[], ...] containing the input
₳ ... )                reduce (so each time we take the list and one character)
  :"01T"$c             check if the character is one of 0, 1, or T
  [ ... | ...          IF-ELSE
    "01"$Ḟ&            if so, then just append it (-1 for T)
    ...                else:
      $ṫ$ṫ$^           pop the last two off the list and reorder the stack
      "&|cs"$Ḟ         find the character in "&|cs"
      ᵈgᵈGᵉ-±ᵈ∨;JJiĖ&  index into a list of the aforementioned functions
"01T"i                 finally, index into "01T" to format the output
```

Although this uses `Ė`, that's just to execute the function. It isn't being used as `eval` here; Vyxal just overloads that character to mean many things.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 52 bytes

```
f=lambda s:s.pop(0)(f(s),f(s))if 1<s[0]else s.pop(0)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dVFNisIwFGa2OcWD2TTQSisuBjHgBToXECkxTWYC-SOJYM_ixs0wZ9LTGFOKUHTzXvL9vC-8nP_dEH-tWV4uf8coqq_rShBF9aGnENZh4awralyIIuDyUbAU0GzCrt5zFThMgtF7-9h-wreNfA2aOifNTwDqOVijBpCGqWPPexDWA1PUyzggTbQ0qCWanhAjTDsUiDRx0XXWdx1CzqdbSt-xEuoSmj3GTyyUUDVzsM1CneAHO6cmPInmo5JrrO-Zl_FsbLMslj1Ntr2k6sym97TTOcvGRU6fcQc)

Takes input in Polish notation with the following mapping:

```
LT -> -1
EQ -> 0
GT -> 1

min -> min
max -> max
compare -> cmp
(<>) -> int.__or__
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 88 bytes

```
{`(?=(S.?L|S.?E?|B.?G|B.?E?|OE?.|CE.|CLG|CGL)(?<=(.))).[GEL]{2}
$2
CGE
L
CLE
G
CLL|CGG
E
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYshD0IxDIR9fwdiMxNP89JkzaXmkolJQgICgUEQ3Bu/fXRB3Jfr9e79@Dxf9zmPW9I99aIcAeioRX0hbIOWYQjRhzlz0vOeSs65XBy8HttXTpuYQyhGiAcZTRfMueJGl4rulBqIGw1/evwa16xFz3qFM9If) Link includes test cases. Key: `L` - `LT`; `E` - `EQ`; `G` - `GT`; `S` - `min`; `B` - `max`; `C` - `compare`, `O` - `(<>)`. Note that `C`s operands are reversed (test cases have been adapted accordingly). Explanation:

```
{`
```

Repeat until no more operators can be reduced.

```
(?=(S.?L|S.?E?|B.?G|B.?E?|OE?.|CE.|CLG|CGL)(?<=(.))).[GEL]{2}
$2
```

Look for an operator followed by two operands, where one of the operands is also the result, in which case replace the trio with that operand.

```
CGE
L
CLE
G
CLL|CGG
E
```

Replace trios where the result does not match any of the operands.

- `S.?L`: `min` when at least one operand is `L` is that operand, otherwise
- `S.?E?`: `min` of two non-`L` operands is `E` if it is either operand otherwise it is an operand (they are both `G` at this point)
- `B.?G`: `max` when at least one operand is `G` is that operand, otherwise
- `B.?E?`: `max` of two non-`G` operands is `E` if it is either operand otherwise it is an operand (they are both `L` at this point)
- `OE?.`: `(<>)` of `E` with anything is the second operand otherwise it is the first operand
- `CE.`: Reversed compare of `E` with anything is the second operand
- `CLG`: Reversed compare of `L` with `G` is `G`
- `CGL`: Reversed compare of `G` with `L` is `L`

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 103 bytes

```javascript
x=>x.map(i=>a.push(i<2?i:[p=>p<q?p:q,p=>p<q?q:p,p=>(p>q)-(q>p),p=>p||q][i-2](a.pop(q=a.pop()))),a=[])|a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY0xC8IwEIV3f0XGBNKiVZfaREREBCtKHYTSIWirETUXq@LQ/14vVSe95T7uvXfvqB6q3F413LyL2eV1IeqnkE//rIBqIZUP9/JAdRQMdZiCkBDZIYSWf9CG4JCCtMyjVgJrlKqyWaq9IKP4wAC14r0ZDlcizVil6vmaCOJ1OJmsENqcTN2hM2jFswVCwEk82iB0ORnHS4QeJ0mSIPQHra25lOaU@yezpwVNJysXb4wZYz/yfP2WMf5P/qadDcubYuerXw)

const `SSS = 5` mean `<>`

Reverse Polish Notation

---

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 64 bytes

-2B from tsh

```javascript
eval
with(Math)M=max,m=min,T=-1,S=(a,b)=>a||b,C=(a,b)=>sign(a-b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dcu9CsIwFEDhvS/Se@FGzCxx6ZypeYGbmraR/IgJ1aHvHkVwERwPH@fKG5fp7m9VpHxxbVbNbRy6h68raK4rahX5SVFFn8goIWlUwGRRnXnfLQ3fKn5JwMJim3IqObhDyAvM0A9wJIk94qn7kRHMH9HvJ4Ikgx9uLw)

Comment: Second answer is invalid, since evaluation returns `-1` and not `T`.

Comment: *whereas input uses `T`

Comment: @Mukundan314 Does removing definition of T fix it?

Comment: Probably, but if using multiple characters for a value is fine, you can also probably do the same for the operators in which cause you only need to define `S` and `C`

Comment: `with(Math)M=max,m=min,T=-1,S=(a,b)=>a||b,C=(a,b)=>sign(a-b)`

Answer (score 2):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 1 byte <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
⍎
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=e9TbBwA&f=40pTUNcw0Dg8XVfTUFOdC8Q7tN6w@lHvLlsDq0e9Wx91twDZtTA5g0c9HRqGj3q6gIo0oWJwPlDOAKYOwwQsQgaapKiG24fNfSBBsCdQ3IXFRrgiqBps9oDVaID9CvIU1K8A&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog-extended&m=train&n=f)

Takes input as a parenthesized infix expression. This does feel a bit like cheating...

Uses this mapping:

```
LT -> ¯1
EQ -> 0
GT -> 1

min -> ⌊
max -> ⌈
compare -> (×-)
(<>) -> {⍺=0:⍵⋄⍺}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 55 bytes

```
ＦＡ≡ιS⊞υ⌊Ｅ²⊟υB⊞υ⌈Ｅ²⊟υC⊞υ⁻›§υ±¹§υ±²‹⊟υ⊟υO⊞υ⊟ΦＥ²⊟υ∨κλ⊞υιＩυ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY9PC8IwDMXvfoqwUwoRnEc9qaAITgcexUOZ1RXrNvpHBfGz11YFFcWcwi/v5SVFyXVRc@X9ttaA06pxFhkDc5K2KAElg0ur4EZAskx6kDtToiPIZCUP7oAZb7BLkNcNOhaq/9QO37X8/Fc7@tzrDE604FZoHNhptRHnOJiLXUCYMkbwjbss8pkwBh/rf8Qs3mLicCxVzPi8imChcU@gHs6N2HKn7MsoA7y2ci0riyNubPT0vV@tOgQpxb8J2rFZJncQcAim@OR67dtHdQM) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as a list in reversed Polish with reversed arguments, i.e. the entire Polish is simply reversed. Key: `-1` - `LT`; `0` - `EQ`; `1` - `GT`; `S` - `min`; `B` - `max`; `C` - `compare`, `O` - `(<>)`. Explanation:

```
ＦＡ≡ι
```

Loop over the input list and switch over each element.

```
S⊞υ⌊Ｅ²⊟υ
```

Handle `S` by pushing the minimum of the top two values to the stack.

```
B⊞υ⌈Ｅ²⊟υ
```

Handle `B` by pushing the maximum of the top two values to the stack.

```
C⊞υ⁻›§υ±¹§υ±²‹⊟υ⊟υ
```

Handle `C` by comparing the top two values. (This is tricky when I don't have a comparison operator.)

```
O⊞υ⊟ΦＥ²⊟υ∨κλ
```

Handle `O` by pushing the first non-zero value of the top two values, if any. (I can't use `Or` itself because it's short-circuiting and would not remove the second value if the first was non-zero.)

```
⊞υι
```

Just push any other values to the stack.

```
Ｉυ
```

Output the final stack (which should hopefully be just one value at this point).

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua 0.10.0](https://www.uiua.org/), 7 bytes

```
quote^!
```

[Try on Uiua Pad!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0-dev_1__IyBFeHBlcmltZW50YWwhCkYhIOKGkCBxdW90ZV4hCkYhIsKvwrEtIDAgMSIKRiEiwrErKy4gwq8xIDEiCkYhIuKGpSAw4oanIDEgwq8xIgpGISLihqXihqcxwq8xIDAiCkYhIsKxKysuIDDCsSsrLiAwIDAiCkYhIsKxKysuIDDCsSsrLiAwIDEiCkYhIsKxKysuIMKvMcKvwrEtIMKvMSDCrzEiCkYhIsKvwrEtwrErKy4gMSAwIMKvMSIKRiEiwq_CsS3CsSsrLiAwIDHihqfihqUgMCAxIMKvMSIK)

This is a macro that takes a string in reverse Polish notation and outputs the result. We use the mapping:

- `GT -> 1`
- `EQ -> 0`
- `LT -> ¯1` (or `` `1 ``)
- `min -> ↧` (or `min`)
- `max -> ↥` (or `max`)
- `comp -> ¯±-` (or `` `sig- ``)
- `(<>) -> ±++.` (or `sig++.`)

Similar to the Vyxal solution, this evaluates the given string as code. We have to use a macro rather than the 6-byte function `quote∘` since quote's function cannot take input by default. As you can see, the entire code and test cases can be written entirely in ASCII, which is rare for Uiua.

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 157 bytes

A port of [@Mukundan314's Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/271835/110802) in Scala.

---

Golfed version. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jZJRa9swEMehj_kUR54kUNI4eSkODgzaQmFhlG4vCyHRNKlxsWVHumQxXT9JKfRle9knaj9Nz3IySjPSPVg6yb-7-__Pvv_tlczk4M-k3bHFD-lse_r0tfh2oxXCWKYWblsA37WBnA5MumsfwwfnZDW5Qpfa6ymP4YtNERIiCT0-hvOVVZgWFrAqNZjCQVFqJ-sr_2uFpnPy9BBeXSbswqKghycjWlt1H8N8fKWXkxlVZk3QEJ4koFrcKuk1W8aXPI4xGa1lxlwkXJ8nhiEf0hncgGIX8SFzg-4sEkvm-qIO-5wP63RYh1yGYt2V_sJ6lFbpT2ZCjab8rhH5fCTJT3B0qk1qNeBCk4ayJNsemNna9Dx4VJl0KVYhpRaRx-QP2EZAxSEZ0TBx0c1phuHmLzYmDPY5uXnDqbfcpquKvJROfy7YK87vcfATqtbOydlG5mWmPRQGVp6MBFM7KzA380CW9Gkxs8ywj6lHpgT0BESc1yP8F-AFdKKDxDiUyImp0YPcDqKMgx2pXrP-J_a-ftVsh_SpUC0KBd_negElQ-Nd_CrnrrX90x4fm_0F)

```scala
type Q=(Int,Int)=>Int
def f(s:Seq[_]):(Seq[_],Int)=s match{case(q:Q)::t=>val(r1,r2)=f(t);val r3=f(r1);(r3._1,q(r2,r3._2));case v::t=>(t,v.asInstanceOf[Int])}
```

Ungolfed version. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jZTBbtQwEIYvnHLmAUY92VJ22ywXFKlIlQCpElEPwGm1ooOxu0aJbdlO2Qj2Sbj0AhfeiKdh4iTbFVu2XOzE_uaffzyWv_8MAmt89mt5MjP2C3pzsrr70UY1e_77yVP78bMUESrUBr5mAKen8Lo1ImprIHZOgrIerJMe-6VARFq9cnAO7NLEHGjgcP6inzPa_iQVNKTG0N-EEi68x275Nnptbla8hPdGRwrtU6VkL6XSRkJcS_BStD7oW8o5ObhW1wnsRRUjuTc6xOWF6XoptvuZTECg1FGsR3kAgUECs64kwxzKEiLqmsyO2wC3WAPzMsQip_yhrWPR6yjWg_wQW0zYYsBS6D03MdaxUe2e5_ueSLCVe4YgJcyH9TmGSxMiGiGv1JJKWw2x2-yBU2vQOTrbAGw6tcBT00SNXscum_w35di1TQ5d6liFcT1vqFVpZQdW_wBx8xcoDsDNXNjGoZfvLNsDwyEI36DblfNqg42rZQCroA1UTars4BY4ukSxNkylzjORw1kOBefzDwv-EBBymBVHiSpJNMT06FFugijiaEbSG8b_xB73L4bpmD-R1Iok-Dh3llAqqJq-92K22XZ4HMY34m6c_wA)

```scala
object Main {
  // Function type for operations
  type Op = (Int, Int) => Int

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    // Define the recursive function `f`
    def f(s: List[Any]): (List[Any], Int) = s match {
      case (op: Op) :: tail =>
        val (rest1, result1) = f(tail)
        val (rest2, result2) = f(rest1)
        (rest2, op(result1, result2))
      case value :: tail => (tail, value.asInstanceOf[Int])
    }

    // Define the mappings (functions) for clarity
    val m: Op = (x, y) => Math.min(x, y)
    val M: Op = (x, y) => Math.max(x, y)
    val c: Op = (x, y) => x.compareTo(y)
    val s: Op = (x, y) => x | y

    // Examples of using the function `f`
    println(f(List(c, 0, 1))._2)
    println(f(List(s, -1, 1))._2)
    println(f(List(M, 0, m, 1, -1))._2)
    println(f(List(M, m, 1, -1, 0))._2)
    println(f(List(s, 0, s, 0, 0))._2)
    println(f(List(s, 0, s, 0, 1))._2)
    println(f(List(s, -1, c, -1, -1))._2)
    println(f(List(c, s, 1, 0, -1))._2)
    println(f(List(c, s, 0, 1, m, M, 0, 1, -1))._2)
  }
}
```